# Chance of success with diplomatic missions

Tags: illyriad

The 2009 guide, [Diplomatic Missions in Illyriad](http://forum.illyriad.co.uk/3-diplomatic-missions-in-illyriad_topic43.html), lists a number of factors that influence the chance of success with diplomatic missions, including

> - strength and number of the units carrying out the mission,
> - strength and number of the units defending against the mission (but only if the defending player has the Counter-Intelligence technology researched),
> - size of the target city (smaller towns have a higher chance of detecting strangers from afar)
> - level of the Consulate of the player who sent the mission (ie the 'training' of his or her units)
> - level of the Consulate of the defending player's Counter-Intelligence agents (ie the 'training' of his or her units)

but it gives no further detail, let alone formulae, about what weight is attached to these factors.  Do we have a more precise understanding of how to determine the prospects of success for diplomatic missions?

Comment: Belegar Ironhammer says he has good results from just sending all his units and hoping for the best

Answer (score 2):

Some info about critical success/failure.

-Only diplomatic missions of at least 100 units have a 1% chance of a critical success.

-Only diplomatic missions of less than 100 units have a 1% chance of a critical failure.

http://forum.illyriad.co.uk/changes-to-diplomatic-unit-critical-chances_topic5417.html